# Dynamically adjusting three column design with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I'm trying to make a three column layout that can be dynamically resized in the browser by the user.  I'm using jQuery to control the resizing of the columns. The first two columns adjust perfectly, but I can't seem to get the right two columns to function the appropriate way.

When the mouse drags to the left, the columns adjust to the right.  Any help in getting this to work the right way would be great!  The jQuery I'm using is below and here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cleverdirt/hsaL9/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".first").on("mousedown", function(e){
    mousedownFirst = true;
  });
  $(".second").on("mousedown", function(e){
    mousedownSecond = true;
  });
  $(".container").on("mouseup", function(e){
    mousedownFirst = false;
    mousedownSecond = false;
  });
  $(".container").on("mousemove", function(e){

    var offset = $(this).offset().left;

    if(mousedownFirst){
      $(".left").css("width", e.pageX - offset);
      $(".middle").css("left", e.pageX - offset);
    }
    if(mousedownSecond){
      $(".right").css("width", e.pageX - offset);
      $(".middle").css("right", e.pageX - offset);
    }

  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cleverdirt/hsaL9/

Answer (score 0):

Basically your offset is always 0. What you need to do is, store the currently dragged barhandle into a variable and on mousemove retrieve the offset from this object rather then $(this) in this context.

something like:

```
$(".first").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    mousedownFirst = true;
    current = $(this);
});
$(".second").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    mousedownSecond = true;
    current = $(this);
});
$(".container").on("mouseup", function (e) {
    mousedownFirst = false;
    mousedownSecond = false;
    current = null;
});
$(".container").on("mousemove", function (e) {
    if (current == null) { return; }
    var offset = $(this).offset().left;
    ......
});
```

That also reduces mousemove overhead if no element is selected for drag.
In Addition you need to adjust your widh/left/right values. Always Interpolate over the current values calculating the delta and subtracting/adding this to the value.